# Retrieving the value of the field when the FK target doesn't exist

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys

In my project I have two models:

```
ModelA(models.Model):
   seq = models.ForeignKey('ModelB')
   foo = models.CharField()
ModelB(models.Model):
   seq = models.ForeignKey(ModelA)
   bar = models.CharField()
```

In the project flow ModelB are created after ModelA, but the seq value in ModelA is already set.

The problem is that before the creation of ModelB objects I need to access ModelA.seq, and even the column having values I can't because Django tries to fetch ModelB instead of seq value.

The access is something like:

```
...
current_seq = modelA.seq
...
```

There is a way to access seq value when the corresponding FK object doesn't exists?